# can't import custom python module in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get my vscode project to mimic functionality that pycharm is able to produce. With pycharm, I'm able to create, via an XML, a custom pycharm project file that lists the various different sources of the different folder locations of the custom modules I need to have available.

In vscode, I'm going about this by creating a workspace file and adding these sources as folders in the JSON object. The workspace will populate properly in vscode, but when I try to reference an import, Intellisense is able to see the module I'm trying to import [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3R5O.png) but when I try to start a debug session, vscode barfs and says it can't find this module [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN2pq.png).

My folder structure is:

workspace

|--> obscura

|-->|--> obscura

|-->|-->|--> database.py

|-->|--> obscura_test

|-->|-->|--> mytestfile.py --- where I'm starting debug session

Here are the screenshots:

[image: Intellisense]

-- Intellisense shows what the module is

[image: fail to import]

-- Vscode fails on debug

Comment: would you be able to share the proj directory in zip?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in my python project in `VSCode`

If my module is a class

```py
from folder_name.python_file_name_without_extension import class_name

# then I can use it as follow
class_name.function_name()
```

If my module is just a script

```py
from folder_name.python_file_name_without_extension import function_name

# then I can use it as follow
function_name()
```

Comment: When you specify the folder_name, are you doing full path, or relative to workspace? I'm trying to support functionality with other team members who use pycharm, and the project workspace in pycharm once defined will define python paths as relative

Comment: if you have another folder, just add that folder name with "." to the `from` clause. Example in your folder structure: `from obscura.obscura.database import your_function_name`

Comment: That would change the actual python code, and this behavior already works for the majority of my team via pycharm. I was hoping to understand why I feel like I'm almost there, because intellisense can recognize the module in my workspace, but debugging can't